# Multiple MKPolygon changes color after zoom level changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkpolygon

Hello i am working on map related app in which i have to draw multiple polygon on mk mapview. it's load fine at first time .
[image]

As you can see in image.but if i change the zoom level all the colours are changed in mapview as shown in picture below.
[image]

```
-(MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
 if([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolygon class]]){
MKPolygonRenderer *renderer = [[MKPolygonRenderer alloc] initWithPolygon:overlay];
            renderer.fillColor=noflyzonecolor;
            renderer.strokeColor=noflyzonestrokecolor;
            renderer.lineWidth=strokeWidth;
  return renderer;
}
}
```

Comment: Are `noflyzonecolor` and `noflyzonestrokecolor` constants or variables? Log what colors they are or add a “watch” on them and I’ll wager they’re getting changed somewhere.

Comment: they are not constant they are variables  its depending on API response . As i said its load fine at first time.

Comment: Well, the problem would appear to rest in how you parsed the API response and updated these variables and then initiated the adding of the overlays. And, btw, if the color is an attribute of the overlay, you should create an overlay subclass with that property. But we’re just guessing until you show how the parsing and adding of overlays works.